# Selenium: How to extract new HTML snippet generated by user interaction?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, calendar

**Background**

I am writing a script to automate web form submissions for a set of websites using Python and Selenium. However, the script needs to work on similar websites where the underlying HTML and general structure of a form is **not known** in advance.

I have managed to get this working well for standard input fields (e.g. text fields, radio buttons, etc), however I am having difficulty handling date picker fields, as these fields are very site-specific.

Despite these site-specific differences, there appears to be a common usage pattern: (i) click the date picker field to reveal the calendar pop-up; then (ii) click on the desired date.

Revealing the pop-up calendar by clicking on the date picker field is straightforward and results in a new snippet of HTML (defining the calendar) being inserted somewhere within the page source. If I could extract just this new HTML snippet then I could use this information to reason about the input field being a calendar and how to interact with it.

**Question**

How can I extract new HTML code that was generated by a user interaction, such as clicking on an input field?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited response according to user's feedbacks**

### Get html content of element

How to get & print `WebElement` instance content with python / selenium:

```
my_web_element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
# Or, depending what you want
my_web_element.get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

### How to wait for an element

In this example I click on a link with id 'target' and wait for an element with id 'calendar' is visible.

```
driver.find_element_by_id('target').click()
calendar = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'calendar'))
)
```

### Conclusion

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui  import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('http://spam.egg.bacon')

driver.find_element_by_id('target').click()
calendar = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'calendar'))
)

print calendar.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Prints: `<div id="calendar">I'm a calendar</div>` with this complet example: https://gist.github.com/arount/285e5add758bb14074efc4708f1d6b07

Comment: Yes, the injected HTML is visible if I get the page source after the action. However, I am only able to get the entire page source, which will require doing a "diff" on the before and after source code to extract the injected code. Is there a way to directly extract the newly injected HTML without doing a before/after diff?